# Adapting the limits in Matplotlib after 2D transform

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, cgaffinetransform

I want to change the value of the plot axes after performing a transformation from an image. Without any transformation, the x-y limits are simply the dimensions of the image. First I apply extent to change the limits at **imshow**, but after that, I need to a second transformation using matplotlib (a transformation matrix that implies scaling and translation.

I followed the steps in the [following tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/affine_image.html), but all I get is a completely white plot. If I don't add the extent part in imshow, what I get is a plot with the x-y coordinates in pixels (not wanted), but with the data plotted in the correct position (near 2e-3 for the x axis and 4e-4 for the y-axis).

```
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = limits # limits are calculated before
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ims = ax.imshow(data, clip_on = True, extent = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax],  norm = LogNorm(), cmap = colourmap)
trans_data = transform + ax.transData
ims.set_transform(trans_data)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = ims.get_extent()
ax.plot([x1, x2, x2, x1, x1], [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1], "y--", transform = trans_data)

ax.set_xlim(x1,x2)
ax.set_ylim(y1,y2)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
fig.colorbar(ims, ax = ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(plot_title + '.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: A side note: you are mixing two different ways of using Matplotlib. See https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/ .

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried a more OO oriented code, by simply relying on the ax object. While this fixes the problem regarding the limits, now the transformation does not seem to affect the image data (even though it affects the x-y limits).